# How to make for loop with pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make for loop formation with dataframe but i couldn't find grammar rule with this situation. Below is an overview of the functions I want to implement.
With Detail, i want to make new column named [df] which is calculated with column[f_adj]'s value.
[Image of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmcuS.png)

How to I fix this code?

```
df1['df'] = 0
for i in range(1,len(df1)-1):
        df1['df'[i]] = df1['f_adj'[i+1]] - df1['f_adj'[i-1]]
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should used `iloc` or `loc` in your code.

Comment: thanks, i fixed with that function.